# HTML in between h3/h2 tags with Xpath/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, xpath, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm using `Scrapy` for a project and I get the following html:

```
<h3><span class="my_class">First title</span></h3>
<ul>
    <li>Text for the first title... li #1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Text for the first title... li #2</li>
</ul>
<h3><span class="my_class">Second title</span></h3>
<ul>
    <li>Text for the second title... li #1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Text for the second title... li #2</li>
</ul>
```

Now, when I use `response.xpath(".//ul/li/text()").extract()` it does work, it gives me `["Text for the first title... li #1", "Text for the first title... li #2", "Text for the second title... li #1", "Text for the second title... li #2"]` But this is partially what I want.

I want two lists, one for `First title` and another one for `Second title`. 
That way the outcome will be:

```
first_title = ["Text for the first title... li #1", "Text for the first title... li #2"]
second_title = ["Text for the second title... li #1", "Text for the second title... li #2"]
```

I still don't have a clue how to achieve this. I'm currently using `Scrapy` to get the HTML; A solution using `xpath` with pure `Python` will be ideal for me. But somehow I believe `BeautifulSoup` will be useful for this kind of task.

Do you have any ideas how to perform this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath and CSS selectors in Scrapy.

Here's an example solution (in an ipython session ; I only changed #1 and #2 in the 2nd block to #3 and #4 to make is more obvious):

```
In [1]: import scrapy

In [2]: selector = scrapy.Selector(text="""<h3><span class="my_class">First title</span></h3>
   ...: <ul>
   ...:     <li>Text for the first title... li #1</li>
   ...:     <li>Text for the first title... li #2</li>
   ...: </ul>
   ...: <h3><span class="my_class">Second title</span></h3>
   ...: <ul>
   ...:     <li>Text for the second title... li #3</li>
   ...:     <li>Text for the second title... li #4</li>
   ...: </ul>""")

In [3]: for title_list in selector.css('h3 + ul'):
   ...:         print title_list.xpath('./li/text()').extract()
   ...:     
[u'Text for the first title... li #1', u'Text for the first title... li #2']
[u'Text for the second title... li #3', u'Text for the second title... li #4']

In [4]: for title_list in selector.css('h3 + ul'):
        print title_list.css('li::text').extract()
   ...:     
[u'Text for the first title... li #1', u'Text for the first title... li #2']
[u'Text for the second title... li #3', u'Text for the second title... li #4']

In [5]:
```

---

Edit, after OP's question in comment:

> Every `<li>` tag is enclosed in its own `<ul>` (...) Is there any way to extend that to make it look for all the `ul` tags below the `h3` tag?

If `h3` and `ul` are all siblings, one way to select the `ul`s that are before the next `h3` is to count [preceding `h3` siblings](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes)

Consider this input HTML snippet:

```
<h3><span class="my_class">First title</span></h3>
<ul><li>Text for the first title... li #1</li></ul>
<ul><li>Text for the first title... li #2</li></ul>

<h3><span class="my_class">Second title</span></h3>
<ul><li>Text for the second title... li #3</li></ul>
<ul><li>Text for the second title... li #4</li></ul>
```

The first `<ul><li>` line has 1 precending `h3` sibling, the 3rd `<ul><li>` line has 2 preceding `h3` siblings.

So for each `h3`, you want following `ul` siblings which have exactly the number of `h3` you've seen so far.

First:

`following-sibling::ul[count(preceding-sibling::h3)=1]`

then,

`following-sibling::ul[count(preceding-sibling::h3)=2]`

and so on.

Here is this idea in action with the help of `enumerate()` on `h3` selection (remember that [XPath positions start at 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates), not 0):

```
In [1]: import scrapy

In [2]: selector = scrapy.Selector(text="""
<h3><span class="my_class">First title</span></h3>
<ul><li>Text for the first title... li #1</li></ul>
<ul><li>Text for the first title... li #2</li></ul>

<h3><span class="my_class">Second title</span></h3>
<ul><li>Text for the second title... li #3</li></ul>
<ul><li>Text for the second title... li #4</li></ul>
""")

In [3]: for cnt, title in enumerate(selector.css('h3'), start=1):
   ...:     print title.xpath('following-sibling::ul[count(preceding-sibling::h3)=%d]/li/text()' % cnt).extract()
   ...: 
[u'Text for the first title... li #1', u'Text for the first title... li #2']
[u'Text for the second title... li #3', u'Text for the second title... li #4']
```

Comment: I really appreciate this elegant solution, I learned many things from this code. The thing is that I made a mistake. Every `<li>` tag is enclosed in its own `<ul>`. For example: `<ul><li>Text for the first title... li #1</li></ul><ul><li>Text for the second title... li #3</li></ul>`. I edited the question. Is there any way your code will work with that `html`?

Comment: Now I get `[u"Text for the first title... li #1"]` and `[u"Text for the second title... li #3"]`. I know this is because the selector `'h3 + ul'` looks for the tag `h3` and then its first `ul` tag. Is there any way to extend that to make it look for all the `ul` tags below the `h3` tag?

Comment: @gglasses, I've edited my answer with a solution to your 2nd use-case

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this with Beautiful Soup would be the following. (I've stored the results in a dict rather than separately named lists, in case you don't know in advance how many you'll have.)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
groups = soup.find_all('ul')
results = {}
for group in groups:
   results[group.find_previous_sibling().text] = [e.text for e in a.find_all('li')]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use BeautifulSoup you can utilize the `findNext` method:

```
h3s = soup.find_all("h3")
for h3 in h3s:
    print h3.text
    print h3.findNext("ul").text
```

In this case BS is a bit easier to use because it can find siblings of elements easier.

With simple XPath you could do something like this:

```
h3s = data.xpath('//h3')
for h3 in h3s:
    print h3.xpath('.//text()')
    h3.xpath('./following-sibling::ul')[0].xpath('.//text()')
```

This is fixed for your example above. If you need some general approach I would say BS is the right tool because of the methods available.